# Ordered HTML list with special kind of numbering — is there any simple way?

Tags: html, css, list

How to make a list in HTML with exactly this kind of numbering, please?

(01) Itemitemitemitem
(02) Itemitemitemitem
(03) Itemitemitemitem
(04) Itemitemitemitem

But notice, please, that I am just complete amateur, so I need really simple and friendly explanation.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "numbering"? Also, we expect at least some code showing what you have attempted, even if it doesn't work. Please, take a look at [ask] and maybe [mcve] could be useful too

Comment: would : `ol{list-style:decimal-leading-zero}`be enough ? please add your HTML code and your css attempts

Comment: You should add your code to the question, and the most usefull, so you get efficeint help , no one has to guess if willing to help, you get  no downvote and  nor a closed question :) Welcome on SO.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter) if `(` & `)` are also required to be seen:

> The `counter()` CSS function returns a string representing the current value of the named counter, if there is one. It is generally used with pseudo-elements, but can be used, theoretically, anywhere a  value is supported.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;/* remove the marker */
  /* mind also other list style */
  counter-reset: count;
}

li {
  counter-increment: count;
}

li::before {
  content: "(" counter(count, decimal-leading-zero) ") ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> Item</li>
  <li> Item</li>
  <li> Item</li>
  <li> Item</li>
  <li> Item</li>
  <li> Item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add the list-style-type:

```css
ol { list-style-type: none;counter-reset: item;padding:0 }
li { counter-increment: item; }
li:before { content: " ("counter(item,decimal-leading-zero)") "; }
```

```html
<ol>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: not too sure this enough, ( & ) might still be missing here ;)

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: the OP clarified minutes ago about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use disable default list-style-type and use a custom list-style-type using the counter property and pseudo-element ::before https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp.

With this property, you can use it with something other than

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: step;
}

li {
  counter-increment: step;
}

li:before {
  content: "("counter(step, decimal-leading-zero)") ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you can use the `<ol>` tag. This stands for **ordered list** and will number your list items for you.

The list items will use the `<li>` tag. This stands for **list item**.

For example:

```html
    <ol>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: That does not answer the question. It wil produce 1,2,3...instead of 01,02,03